# Knapsack displaying all sub sets

Tags: c++, arrays, subset, knapsack-problem

I am having difficulty implementing a particular variation of the knapsack problem. the prompt wants every possible subset of items to be displayed like so.

set 1: {}    => capacity: 0, value: $0

set 2: {1}   => capacity: 3, value: $12

set 3: {2}   => capacity: 4, value: $10

set 4: {1,2} => capacity: 7 – over capacity, value: N/A

```
Solution: {1}   => capacity: 3, value: $12
```

I have implemented an algorithm to just give me the max value (which would be 12 in the example above) and that works fine. But I think I would have to change my approach completely in order to achieve the wanted output. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
    int i, w;
    int K[n + 1][W + 1];

    // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || w == 0)
                K[i][w] = 0;
            else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
                K[i][w]
                        = max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
            else
                K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
        }
    }

    return K[n][W];
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual implementation or at least describe it. If you have used dynamic programming, it is not possible to directly show all subsets; you would have to use explicit enumeration of all subsets (where some branches of the search tree perhaps might be omitted).

Comment: @Codor Yes I did use dynamic programming. I have put the function above.